# how can I compile SASS to CSS in Bracket IDE?

Tags: sass, adobe-brackets

I have been working coding on bracket text editor for several days but I don't know how compile my SCSS codes to CSS!!

I have also installed bracket sass extension , have I installed right extension or not? if I have, so how does it work?

this is my extension manager:[image]

Comment: Click on "More Info"

Comment: I wouldnt use this plugin as it will only use Libsass and Ruby. Both depreciated in favor of Dart Sass. Get something like Prepros, its much easier

Comment: So, how would I use Prepros? and can I use it in Bracket text editor? if so how?

Comment: Prepros is a stand-alone compiler.  You install it, add your project to it, and it will automatically compile JS and SASS. You can tell it where to compile to, have all kinds of options, create source maps etc. Just google Prepros. Easiest compiler around

Answer (score 0):

[image: Try installing another extension. I had the same problem. I installed the live sass compiler extension. It worked for me.]

Try installing the live sass compiler. After that, prepare the settings.json file below.

```
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
        "format": "expanded",
        "extension": ".css",
        "savePath": "~",
    },
    {
        "format": "compressed",
        "extension": ".min.css",
        "savePath": "~",
    }
],
```

Comment: live sass compiler exist in VSCODE, but I want compile sass in bracket text editor

Comment: Followed this tutorial?

https://harikrishkk.blogspot.com/2016/01/brackets-sass-plugin-setup.html